# Detecting last added feature for custom plugin using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I made a custom plugin to create and delete features, but I need to detect the last added feature id.

When I recently added it to layer, the id is always 0.

I tried to use the QgsVectorLayer signal 'featureAdded' like this:

```
layer.featureAdded.connect(self.test)

def test(self, fId):
    print(fId)
```

The signal is not triggered when I create the feature using python code.

Comment: Can you add the code you use to add the feature to the layer?